# Ubuntu apps open off screen

Tags: 16.04

Some apps on my Ubuntu 16.04 open off screen

[image: Example]

If I create a new user, all apps open as they should. How can I either reset the open position or wipe the current user settings?

Comment: Just did my normal apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade routine, and started having this issue.  The proposed fix solved the problem.

Comment: Is there a solution without having to install CompizConfig Setting Manager?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I figured it out.

1. Open: CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Select: Window management from the left pane
   [Compiz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twpmO.jpg)
3. Make sure Place windows is selected
   [Window Management options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0lbk.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I tried the CompizConfig Settings Manager answer above but needed the following changes to make it work (I don't have enough "reputation" points to comment so have to add a separate answer):

1. I didn't have the CompizConfig Settings Manager installed so I needed to run:
     `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Ticking the ***Place*** **Window Management** option by itself didn't work for me, I **also** had to tick the ***Snapping Windows*** option.